# How to code a GIF in a Google Chrome Extension?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome-extension

I am a beginner at creating chrome extensions. My group and I had an idea where we make the extension halloween themed. For my part of the project, I have to have a black cat walk across the screen, but I am unsure where to even start with this code. Would anyone be able to help me? Let me know if you need more information!

I am unsure where to even start.

Comment: Start with the beginning: find and study a tutorial on extensions and/or the official documentation [overview article](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview). Also inspect/debug/study the [demo extensions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a starting point for you.

```css
@keyframes move {
  from {
    left: 0
  } to {
    left: 100%
  }
}

body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

#cat {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: black;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  animation: 5s linear move;
}
```

```html
<div id='cat'>
```

Comment: It's not a starting point, it's a random point. The OP needs to learn what extensions are, and how to make them, which is not the kind of question answerable on StackOverflow.

Comment: @wOxxOm I'm just showing them some of the components to do what they want. There's so much out there, sometimes it's hard to even know how to look for it. But perhaps you're right, maybe I shouldn't call it a "starting point".

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! It is a starting point, but I looked over multiple videos to learn how to begin with Google Extensions. Something VERY new still, but I think I can def move forward with this information. @Mason